# 8080 or 8081 is tomcat or we can use it for any application

Tags: tomcat

I come across a URL where it has 8081 as port.

In general can we have 8081 for any application or it is reserved for tomcat server. Can we have 8081 for any other server like web logic or web-sphere or jboss?

thanks.

Comment: They are not reserved by IANA but they are pretty generally used for Tomcat. Avoid them if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, any other application which is using HTTP can use 8080 as port. Its an alternative to HTTP port 80 but you will have to include it in url if you want your application to run on 8080.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use it for any application. However, it's regarded as "reserved" for web applications like Tomcat or Weblogic. But as long as it doesn't collide with existing application using that port - you can use it.